How can I track C++'s memory allocation module-wise by Allocator?
I have a large C++ program which uses much of the standard libraries. It also uses C-style allocation malloc much. I want to analyze how much memory is consumed in one module.
In short, Mgrx are all very complicated classes. They consist of various fields, in which the standard libraries and custom-defined classes are widely used. Now I want to check how much memory Module1 consumes. I want to it less manually.
struct Mgr1;

struct Mgr2;

struct Mgr3;


struct Module1 {
    vector<Mgr1> v1;
    vector<Mgr1> v3;
    ...
};


struct Module2 {
    vector<Mgr1> v2;
    vector<Mgr1> v3;
};

Generally, there are several utils for problem:

Jemalloc
Which means I can use thread.allocatedp to track thread-wise allocation. If my program is moduled by thread pools(which means every module uses its own dedicated thread pool to consume requests, and communicate with each other by sending messages), then it is a good idea.
mmap/sbrk
I have totally got rid of directly calling mmap or sbrk for memory allocations. So all memory allocations are "delegated" by jemalloc
The arena of Jemalloc

We can bind some threads to their dedicated arena, so the size of each arena represents memory "owned" by this thread.
If the program is not moduled by thread pools, then we can use the mallocx in specific modules. For example, given a module A which calls module B. If we want to compute how much memory module B consumes, then we can replace all malloc with mallocx, providing a MALLOCX_ARENA which specifies a dedicated arena for module B. Thus, the size of this arena is the memory "owned" by module B.



Aboving is general ideas of how to track memory thread-wise or module-wise. However, it is difficult to implement when using C++. Because:

C++'s standard libraries uses Allocator to specify how to allocate memories. We can't just replace malloc with mallocx by some macro magic. We have to defined our own Allocator. It is kind of difficult, even the simplest std::string should be replaced with std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Myallocator<char>> s.
Allocators have types, vector<T, ThisAllocator<T>> differs from vector<T, ThatAllocator<B>>. Moreover, if we have some vector<vector<T>> or ever complicated types, we have to use scoped_allocator_adaptor.

As a result, it is very hard to track memory allocation of all instances of a certain class or module.
I wonder if it is some easier ways that won't reduce the performance too much? IMO, if every fields and sub-fields of Mgr1 uses some kind of Allocator, then I can record memory usage in this allocator's allocate method. However, how can I enforce a custom Allocator for and only for Mgr1 and all its direct or indirect sub-fields?

jemalloc can replace malloc on a process-wide level on Linux, via LD_PRELOAD_LIBRARY

Yes, but I don't want a process level. I just want all fields in Module1 allocates from a dedicated arena specified by mallocx
